# MSW with Jest (confusion)

Tags: jestjs, msw

I am trying to test a component that calls an API, i came across MSW and thought this would be great.

```
const server = setupServer(
    rest.get('http://localhost:3001/vote/test-slug', (req, res, ctx) =>
        res(ctx.delay(500), ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ data: {alreadyVoted: `1`}} )),
    ),
);
```

This is the server i have setup to handle the catch. Under the hood i use fetch to do API calls within my component and it looks something like this

```
apiFetchData = (params) => {
   const res = await fetch(url, options);
   const data = (await res.json()) || null;


   const response: fetchJsonResponse = {
        data,
        statusCode: res.status,
        error: res.status !== 200,
        success: res.status === 200,
    };
}
```

My component has an onload useeffect like so:

```
const component = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
     async function voteCheck() {
            const result = await apiFetchData(
                'http://localhost:3001/vote/test-slug',
            );
            if (result.data.alreadyVoted) {
                setHasUserVoted(result.data.alreadyVoted);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }
        voteCheck();
   }, []);
}
```

when i run my test

```
await act(async () => {
   render(
     <VoteButton />,
   );
});
```

i get the following error from my apiFetchData

```
UseEffect result {
      data: {
        error: 'invalid json response body at  reason: Unexpected end of JSON input'
      },
      hasData: false,
      statusCode: 500,
      error: true,
      errorType: 'application'
    }
```

(i'm using jest-mock-fetch) and the result i get is this

```
Response {
      size: 0,
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: <Buffer >, disturbed: false, error: null },
      [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
        url: undefined,
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'OK',
        headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
        counter: undefined
      }
    }
```

I'm stuck, it appears that MSW is catching the request from the component, but the response i'm getting seems to be 100% invalid for the fetch and i dont know what is wrong. Any help / tips would be much appreciated.

edit: typo in my setupServer code

Answer (score 5):

OK, so, i FINALLY figured out a solution.

https://giters.com/mswjs/msw/issues/686 found this and it was explaining the same issue i had. Turns our i needed to 'polyfill' fetch. (TBH not sure what this means at this stage) but in the comments people linked to this example and specifically this jest.setup:

https://github.com/mswjs/examples/blob/a8bb071d997a24f3a7f7107cbb414659c22ccc5a/examples/with-jest/jest.setup.js#L2

Now that i have `import 'whatwg-fetch';` it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, node does not have `fetch()` out of the box. Pretty interesting that you saw error message on JSON, not about `fetch()` missed